# Laravel complex orderBy

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I have a "complex" sorting for a query in Laravel to do and I need your help

If I continue this way, I won't have hairs anymore.

Typically, I have theses tables :

```
-- PLaces
- id
- name
- lat
- lng


-- Categories
- id
- name

-- category_place
- category_id
- place_id
- order
- confirmed
```

So people search for places near a location with a specific category.

I actually use this code to achieve it :

```
$places = Place::where('active', 1)
        ->whereHas('categories', function (Builder $query) use($selectedCategory) {
            $query->where('category_id', $selectedCategory->id);
        })
        ->Results($city->lat, $city->lng);
```

Where Results is a scope with distance calculation.

I easily get places from a distance with associated categories. But I want to get my results in a certain order :

1/ Places with only the searched category
2/ Places who have multi categories but the searched in first position
3/ Places who have multi categories but the searched in second position
... third, fourth ...

How to order my results to have theme in the best order ?

Have a nice day.
Thanks.

Comment: So on what do you exactly want to order ?

Comment: Thanks @frogeyedman, as I wrote :
1/ Places with only the searched category2/ Places who have multi categories but the searched in first position 3/ Places who have multi categories but the searched in second position ... third, fourth ...